# Python functools reduce on pandas merge changing dtypes from float to object

Tags: python, pandas, functools

In Python 3, I am trying to use reduce to merge pandas dataframes.  Unfortunately, the dytpes are all being changed to object in the result.  Is there a way to preserve the dtypes from the original dataframes?  Here is my code:

```
from functools import reduce

# compile the list of dataframes you want to merge
data_frames = [df1, df2, df3]

# merge the database
df = reduce(lambda  left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['Ticker'],
                   how='outer'), data_frames).fillna('void')
```

Comment: From https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html `A DataFrame with mixed type columns(e.g., str/object, int64, float32) results in an ndarray of the broadest type that accommodates these mixed types (e.g., object).`

Comment: Thank you ... so I guess that means I can not merge them this way and preserve the float values.

Comment: If they are all float, they should stay float.

Comment: Unfortunately a mix, but good to know.  Thank you for the additional information.